# Silverlight: Disable Button on validation error? (Trouble with validation)

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a class in my SL4 app that represents a single entity the user is inputing data about. I am doing data validation as follows:

```
    private double cost;
    public string Cost
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0}{1}", DOLLAR_SYMBOL, cost);
        }
        set
        {
            string price = getPriceFromCost(value);
            if (!double.TryParse(price, out cost))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Please enter a number.");
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("Cost");
        }
    }
```

This works great. However, if the user enters a valid value, then an invalid one, ignores the validation error, and hits submit, the entity will be created with the old valid value. I would rather force the user to correct the error. How can I disable the "Add" button?

Also, I would like to do some other forms of validation when the user clicks the add button, but I still want the nice effect of the text input box being highlighted in red, with the message that pops out. How can I do this without throwing `ArgumentExceptions`?

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle a bool along with throwing you exception and bind the IsEnabled of your Button to that bool.

You can do almost any validation task with the WCF RIA Services - I suggest you begin with Jeff Handleys latest blog posts and take it from there.
http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/09/22/RiaServicesStandardValidators.aspx

Comment: Right, but wouldn't I need a bool for every validated field? `IsValidName`, `IsValidDate`, etc. If the user fails to set the input for `Date`, I don't want to enable the button again until valid input is presented for that field.

Comment: that is a very helpful blog post. I've added `[Required]` to several the properties in my data entity class. However, nothing happens in the front end. How can I make this validation occur?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to follow what is said in this [forum thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/153074/341819.aspx). If you are only using exceptions for input validation, then you need to set `NotifyOnValidationError=True` in the binding of your controls and then any errors will be announced in the `BindingValidationError` event of your control.

If you are using Silverlight 4, it is of course better to use `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a property in View Model for storing the state of Button's IsEnabled property (you'll need to bind this property in XAML).
2. You need to now create a delegate + Event for detecting and raising the CostChange event.
3. In view Model, subscribe to this event and set the IsEnabled property defined in 1.